# How to print more than one query result rows in html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
static function mcontent($chkbox){
   $count = count($chkbox);
   foreach ($chkbox as $value){
       $count = count($value);
       for($i=0;$i>$count;$i++) {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `radio_city` where chkid in (\"$value[$i]\")";

   } }
return DB::select($sql);
```

I have checkboxes which are having dynamic ID's in index page on a table (in td),so when user clicks checkboxes then i am posting those values to next page and sending those values to mysql query as i have shown above(to select more than two rows those depends on user selection),So now i am sending those values to query to fetch the rows from database and need to print in html table.

```
array(8) { ["city"]=> string(1) "8" ["duration"]=> string(1) "0" ["frequency"]=> string(1) "0" ["hours"]=> string(1) "0" ["days"]=> string(1) "0" ["checkbox"]=> array(2) { [2]=> string(5) "bang2" [3]=> string(5) "bang3" } ["TotlCost"]=> string(6) "Rs 0/-" ["email"]=> string(25) "prasanna.mundas@gmail.com" } array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#552 (9) { ["state"]=> string(9) "Karnataka" ["city"]=> string(9) "Bangalore" ["station"]=> string(15) "Radio Fever 104" ["language"]=> string(5) "Hindi" ["reach"]=> string(5) "7.90%" ["rate"]=> string(3) "500" ["rank"]=> string(3) "181" ["idnum"]=> int(8) ["chkid"]=> string(5) "bang3" } }
```

I am getting this array so how can i print this

Comment: can you rephrase your question? it is not clear what you want. and _importantly_, you are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Check again the question,I have edited explaination.

Comment: so what is your question? loop over the result and print the table.

Comment: How can print the result in html table

Comment: use [**foreach**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: can you check my array and tell how should i print it

Comment: this is trvial stuff. can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using eloquent and blade

```
myFunction(){
    $someArray =  radioCity::whereIn('chkid',$chkbox);
    return View::make('some.page',compact('someArray'));
}
```

View

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Duration</th>
           <th>yada yada</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       @foreach($someArray as $row)
         <tr>
           <td>{{ $row['city'] }} </td>
           <td>{{ $row['duration'] }} </td>
           <td>{{ $row['yadayada'] }} </td>
         </tr>
       @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
```